# angular.js $resource as a 'service' with dynamic root

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources

I have a JS library that I would like to supply to my clients, that is based on Angular.
It defines a number of services in the following way:

```
angular.module('Services', [
    'ngResource'
]).factory('UserService', function($resource) {
    return function(whatsonUserId) {
        return $resource('/rest/user/:action');
    }
}. factory ...
```

To use my library, my customers simply do:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function(UserService) {
    ...
    UserService().doSomething()
}
```

When my clients use this library, they use it in their own HTML which obviously loads from their own URL, making the root URL incorrect for MY services. So obviously the way to correct this would be to supply an absolute URL to $resource:

```
        return $resource('www.my.server.url/rest/user/:action');
```

But I don't have just one 'my.server.url' - I have a few. I have a staging environment, I have a development environment, and I have production environments - some are per customer.

My question is: Is there a way I could have a generic 'service', and have the users of my library specify the 'server root' for 'Services' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good use case for [provider api](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). You can define your api using the `module.provider`. Define a provider for your server configuration, something like

```
module.provider('serverConfig',function() {
    var serverUrl='val';     //default url
    this.setServerUrl=function(url) {
       serverUrl=url;
    };
    this.$get=[function(){
       return {url:serverUrl};
    }];
})
```

Once you define such a config service, use it in each of your own services like

```
factory('UserService', function($resource,serverConfig) {
    return function(whatsonUserId) {
        return $resource(serverConfig.url+'/rest/user/:action');
    }
```

The provider needs to be configured at the config stage

```
myApp.config(["serverConfigProvider", function(serverConfigProvider) {
  serverConfigProvider.setServerUrl('serverUrlstring');
}]);
```

Comment: Actually, there is no reason for a configurable service (nor for the "provider api"). A plain service is a better (and simpler) option.

Comment: A plain service would have to be configured before any request is made, unlike provider which can be setup at config stage before any other service is setup. And it is not that complex as perceived :)

Comment: I didn't say it is much complex, but it is unnecessarily complex for this kind of stuff. Why not a `value` or `constant` ?

Comment: @Chandermani thanks. Question: If a factory is just syntactic sugar over Provider, wouldn't it make more sense to use a provider in the first place, in my case, instead of a factory? and have the customer initialize it?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, yes we can use constant for it and it would work just fine, but the correlation\context between the setting and the target is lost. Number of libraries for angularjs use this approach.

Comment: If you require custom initialization before using the library, provider is right way, else factory which has a cleaner syntax would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about an earlier version. But as of AngularJS 1.4.3, the following seems to work:

```
.factory('UserService', function($resource) {
  // subdomain is defaulted to www
  return $resource("http://:subdomain.my.server.url/rest/user", {subdomain: 'www'});
})
```

Then the users can call it either with a new subdomain or not:

```
UserService.query({subdomain: 'user001'}).$promise.then(
// => http://user001.my.server.url/rest/user
```

or

```
UserService.query().$promise.then(
// => http://www.my.server.url/rest/user
```

It's static or dynamic... anyway you like it.